# NullPointerException calling JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create()

Tags: java, apache, web-services, maven, soap

I am using CXF (`cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws`, version `3.0.1`) to create a web service client from a wsdl url like so:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setAddress(url.toString());
factory.setServiceClass(MyServicePort.class);
Object service = factory.create();
```

However, the call to `factory.create()` throws a `NullPointerException` with the following stack trace:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean - Creating Service {http://interfaces.project.domain.com/webservice}MyServicePortService from class com.domain.project.webservice.MyServicePort
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.createSoapBinding(SoapBindingFactory.java:219)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.createBindingInfo(SoapBindingFactory.java:206)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractBindingFactory.java:83)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:341)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpointInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:259)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:144)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:157)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)
```

The url that I pass to `setAddress` is of the form: `http://host:port/path/to/service?wsdl`.  I have verified that it is up by doing a `curl` against that url and getting what I would expect in return.

From inspecting the code on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/3.0.1/org/apache/cxf/binding/soap/SoapBindingFactory.java#215), it would appear that the exception comes from a null `WSDLManager` returned from:

```
bs.getExtension(WSDLManager.class);
```

... the code for which, I believe is [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-core/3.0.1/org/apache/cxf/bus/extension/ExtensionManagerBus.java#193).  And that's where my ability to debug this breaks down.

Any ideas what could be causing CXF to throw the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @StackFlowed Certainly not. This is an error inside CXF itself.